Excel CountIF returns result when 0 is expected and search range has leading 0s
I have a range that has one record which has a leading 0, and search criteria which does not have a leading 0, the COUNTIF function is  returning a result, matching 456 to 0456. I expect the criteria 456 to return 0 as that string does not exist in the range.
=COUNTIF(A2:$A$4,C2)


I'm using this function in a conditional format to show records values that exist in a large range, and alternatively, values that do not exist. Because this function is failing, it I'm seeing that a value exists when it does not.
Seems Excel is automatically converting the range to numbers where it can. Is there a way to prevent Excel from converting to a number before comparing?

I used MATCH instead
=MATCH(C2,A2:$A$4,0)


